# Issue with captions over gallery images

Tags: html, css, hover, gallery, caption

My site:
http://www.lotusroomofboca.com/menu.html

I finally got the mouseover to work to show the green color below, but the text captions I put over the images show awkwardly on hover. I want them to show up WITH the green fade. Also, the fade doesn't work if you hover on the captions..

@Trevor here is all the CSS for this gallery:

```
.floated_img {float:left;
               width:210px;
                  height:144px;
                  margin-right:15px;
                  margin-bottom:15px;
                  background-color:#7b8c6f;
                  text-align:center;
                 }  

.floated_img img {width:210px;
                  height:144px;
                  margin-right:15px;
                  margin-bottom:15px;
                  background-color:#7b8c6f;
                  position:absolute
                  } 

.floated_img img:hover {-moz-opacity:0.15;
                        -khtml-opacity: 0.15;
                        opacity: 0.15;
                        transition-duration:0.5s;}  

.caption p {
    font-family: 'Avenir';
    font-size: 15px;

}


.caption {
    z-index: 1000;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    margin: auto;
    display: none;
    pointer-events: none;
}         

.floated_img:hover .caption {z-index:10000;
          color:white;
          text-align:center;
          position:relative;
          margin:auto;
          display:block;}
```

Comment: What code is doing the mouseover fadeout to green?  Can you share the javascript or css that you are using to accomplish that?

Comment: You can check my update and try using `transition: opacity .5s ease-out; -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;` see if that fixes it for you.  What browser are you using?

Comment: I tried your update, it still does it. I'm using Chrome.

Comment: Hmm I am still having trouble on getting it to work on Internet explorer 10.  If you want to add jQuery to your page I could help with a jQuery solution tomorrow.. That might be more viable then `css` for browser compatibility.  I need to go for now but good luck.  Hmm I'm using chrome and it works for me..  Here i'll do a quick update with how you could do it in jQuery.

Comment: It's good enough for now but if you do have a better solution tomorrow, let me know. Tomorrow is the last day I can work on it.

Comment: I did one more `css` update changing `position:absolute` to `position:relative` may get rid of captions popping up above.  Let me know.. Also there may still be an issue on Internet Explorer 10 browsers..  I can look into that tomorrow.

Comment: That worked for Chrome, thanks! Don't worry about IE or jquery, this is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
.caption p {
    font-family: 'Avenir';
    font-size: 15px;
    opacity: .6;  // makes a little of the green color go through
}


.caption {
    z-index: 1000;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    margin: auto;
    display: none;
    pointer-events: none; // new makes it so the caption does not interfere with hover
}
```

**Update 2** Try:

```
.caption {
    z-index: 1000;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;  //new
    top: 25%;
    margin: auto;
    pointer-events: none;
    display: block; 
    opacity: 0; 
    transition: opacity .5s; 
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
}         

.floated_img:hover > .caption {z-index:10000;
          color:white;
          text-align:center;
          position:relative;
          margin:auto;
          opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! Any way to make the captions white? They're a bit washed out with this code.

Comment: @Marissa Oh remove the `opacity` line then.  I'm trying to understand the issue you were having with the captions.. It's that they are showing up too fast then?

Comment: That's better, thanks. And yes they were showing up too fast. The biggest issue was what the pointer-events fixed though.

Comment: it works other than the captions popping up above the gallery for a second.

Comment: @Marissa can you update your live page so I can see it?  Thanks

Comment: @Marissa still looking i'm not too familiar with css, it might be better to use jQuery instead.. But give me a minute..